# Can't add npm to PATH Variable

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm trying to use npm in the command prompt and Its giving me the same error everytime
"'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Now I tried to add some stuff to the PATH Variable but nothing seems to work
Screenshots down below

[NPM ERROR IN CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG3r4.png)

[What I added in the Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QDF7.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLM5H.png)

Comment: The last but one line starts with a semi-colon. Maybe this is messing up your environment. Please remove this line and try again.

Comment: @Dominique It tried and It still doesn't work